# Call function of JS

Tags: javascript, swift

I want to call JS function from swift

I am expecting results of JS in swift. I have lost of functions that's need to be called from swift. There must be include parameters less or with parameters functions. And also include closure for results

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call functions like that:

```
func setCompleteAdInJavaScript() {
    let javascriptFunction = """
    gameState.setCredits('200');
    """
    
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptFunction) { result, error in
        
        if let _ = error {
            print("Error Set Credit")
            
        } else {
            print("Credit set successfully.")
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: you can call this function from func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {self.setCompleteAdInJavaScript()}